# extracting substring using regex in sas

Tags: regex, perl, sas, extract, matching

I have a string like this:

```
dfjkldjfdsldfkdslfkd dfkdjd/FR018/HAHDFKDLFDAFHDKFJL/ABCD//NAME/I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS/JJJJ//NAME/blah blah blah
```

in this string, I want to be able to pull the string `I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS`. In other words, I want to extract everything that follows `/ABCD//NAME/` and before `/JJJJ`.

how can I write this using regular expressions?

thanks

Comment: Are the delimiters constant (`/ABCD//NAME/` and `/JJJJ`)? Or is it based on the number of slashes `/`? What exactly are the rules? This is a **very** simple regex as it stands and you should refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

Comment: Try this: `my ($res) = $str =~ m{/ABCD//NAME/(.*?)/JJJJ}s;`

Comment: @ctwheels yes the delimeters are constant. please help on this. I keep getting errors and cannot figure it out

Comment: @HåkonHægland how would that be written in SAS?

Comment: @pynewbee See my answer for an approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with SAS, but from the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002601903.htm) it seems like you can do:

```
re = prxparse('/\/ABCD\/\/NAME\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/JJJJ/s');
if prxmatch(re, str) then 
    do;
        res = prxposn(re, 1, str);
    end;
```